# How to modify state on parent DOM with child multiple levels below in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am using a combination of `react-router-dom` and `Material-UI` in my app. I've tried to make a very basic example below with the following files:

routes.tsx

```
import { Outlet, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BaseLayout>
      <Outlet />
    </BaseLayout>
  )
}

export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
    ],
  },
])
```

BaseLayout.tsx

```
export const BaseLayout = {children} => {
  return (
    <>
      <head />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <footer />
      <Alert />
    </>
  )
}
```

Home.tsx

```
export const Home = () => (
  <>
    <button /> // <-- I want this button to trigger the Alert and set open to true !
  </>
)
```

Alert.tsx

```
import { Alert as MuiAlert, Snackbar } from "@mui/material"

export const Alert = ({open?, severity?, message?}) => {
  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={500}
      // onClose={handleClose}
      // action={action}
    >
      <MuiAlert severity={severity}>{message}</MuiAlert>
    </Snackbar>
  )
})
```

I am trying to have a single `Alert` component shared across the application that can trigger an alert for different reasons.

I am not sure how to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keeping some state in the `BaseLayout` component for the open/close status of the alert, and move the `Outlet` into `BaseLayout` and provide this state and setter on the outlet's context provider. The `Home` component would use the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook to access the provided context value.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export const BaseLayout = () => {
  const [alertProps, setAlertProps] = React.useState({});

  const onAlertClose = () => setAlertProps({});

  return (
    <>
      <head />
      <main>
        <Outlet context={{ setAlertProps }} />
      </main>
      <footer />
      <Alert {...alertProps} handleClose={onAlertClose} />
    </>
  )
}
```

```
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Home = () => {
  const { setAlertProps } = useOutletContext();

  const openAlert = () => {
    setAlertProps({
      open: true,
      severity: "success",
      message: "Alert is opened!",
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={openAlert}>
        Alert!
      </button> 
    </>
  )
};
```

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <BaseLayout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
    ],
  },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Context.
You can read more at https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext

For example you can create a alterProvider and in that file will there

```
const AlertContext= React.createContext()

function alertReducer(state, action) { //for update state in context
 switch (action.type) {
  //logic here
 }
}

function AlertProvide({children, initialValue, onChange}) {
 const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
    filterReducer,
    typeof initialValue === 'function' ? initialValue() : initialValue,
  )

  useEffectAfterMount(() => {
    if (typeof onChange === 'function') {
      onChange(state)
    }
  }, [state])

  const value = { state, dispatch, columns }
  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  )
}

function useAlert() {
  const context = React.useContext(AlertContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`useAlertmust be used within a AlertProvide`)
  }
  return context
}
```

or you just can use any globle client state managerment like Redux or Mobx.